# REVIT Transfer floor sketch to Void Extrusion in Family

Tags: revit-api, revit

Struggling with some Revit code to copy the profile of a floor and use it as the sketch profile for a void extrusion in a family.

Here is the Full Sharp Development Code.   It half works in my custom project template,  when I try to use it in an out of the box project generated from revit default template it gives the error "a managed exception was thrown by revit or by one of its external applications"

In my template it cannot properly split the curves into a secondary array.  It says the array elements are being changed but when the loop runs again the element i is back to it's original content???   The TaskDialog clearly says the elements have changed, until the loop iterates again.

Full code:  To work it requires a generic family with the name "Void - Custom" to be in the project.    The "If found" near the bottom last page and a half of code, is where the for loop is not behaving as expected.

```
        /*
 * Created by SharpDevelop.
 * User: arautio
 * Date: 4/30/2019
 * Time: 11:10 AM
 * 
 * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
 */
using System;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Structure;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ARC
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.DB.Macros.AddInId("3411F411-6FC1-4A4D-9CFD-37ABB2028A15")]
    public partial class ThisApplication
    {
        private void Module_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Module_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region Revit Macros generated code
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(Module_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(Module_Shutdown);
        }
        #endregion


public void FloorGrating()
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Dictionary<Floor, List<ModelCurve>> dict_SketchLines = new Dictionary<Floor, List<ModelCurve>>();

        UIDocument uidoc = this.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document document = uidoc.Document;
        View activev = document.ActiveView;

        ElementId levelId = null;
        levelId = activev.LevelId;
        Element levelem = document.GetElement( levelId );
        Level lev = document.ActiveView.GenLevel;

          Reference refsel = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Select Floor to Add Grating To");
          Element elem = document.GetElement(refsel.ElementId);

            Floor f = elem as Floor;
            List<ElementId> _deleted = null;
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(document, "temp"))
            {
                t.Start();
                document.Regenerate();
                _deleted = document.Delete(elem.Id).ToList();
                t.RollBack();
            }
            bool SketchLinesFound = false;
            List<ModelCurve> _sketchCurves = new List<ModelCurve>();

            foreach (var id in _deleted)
            {
                ModelCurve mc = document.GetElement(id) as ModelCurve;
                if (mc != null)
                {
                    _sketchCurves.Add(mc);
                    SketchLinesFound = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (SketchLinesFound) break;
                }
            }
            dict_SketchLines.Add(f, _sketchCurves);

        foreach (Floor key in dict_SketchLines.Keys)
        {
            List<ModelCurve> _curves = dict_SketchLines[key];
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("floor {0} has sketchlines:", key.Id));

            foreach (ModelCurve mc in _curves)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}  <{1}>", mc.GetType(), mc.Id));
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<{0}>", mc.GeometryCurve.IsBound.ToString()));

                if (mc.GetType().ToString() == "Autodesk.Revit.DB.ModelArc" && mc.GeometryCurve.IsBound == false)
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Circle Found");
                }
                try
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<{0}  --  {1}>", mc.GeometryCurve.GetEndPoint(0), mc.GeometryCurve.GetEndPoint(1)));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        //TaskDialog.Show("debug", sb.ToString());

        Document docfamily;
        Family fam;

        string ftitle = document.Title;
        string fpath = document.PathName;
        int ftitlelen = ftitle.Length + 4;
        int fpathlen = fpath.Length;
        int finpathlen = fpathlen - ftitlelen;
        string sfinpath = fpath.Substring(0,finpathlen);
        string famname = "GratingVoid";
        string fext = ".rfa";

        int counter = 1;
        while (counter < 100)
        {
            famname = ("GratingVoid" + counter as String);
            Family family = FindElementByName(document,typeof(Family),famname)as Family;
                if( null == family )
                {
                    sfinpath = (sfinpath + famname + fext);
                    counter = 1000;
                }
                counter += 1;
        }

        FilteredElementCollector collector0 = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
        ICollection<Element> collection0 = collector0.WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();
        List<FamilySymbol> fsym0 = new FilteredElementCollector(document).OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).Cast<FamilySymbol>().ToList();
        FamilySymbol famsymb0 = null;
            foreach (FamilySymbol symb in fsym0)
            {
                if (symb.Name == "Void - Custom")
                {
                    famsymb0 = symb as FamilySymbol;
                }
            }

            fam = famsymb0.Family;

            docfamily = document.EditFamily(fam);               
            try
            {
                docfamily.SaveAs(@sfinpath);
            }
            catch
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Could Not Save Void Family");
            }

        using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(docfamily))
            {
               trans.Start("family");
                bool circleflag = false;
                ElementId delid = null;
                FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector( docfamily );
                foreach(Element element in collector.OfClass(typeof(GenericForm)))
                {
                    delid = element.Id;
                }
                docfamily.Delete(delid);

                CurveArray loccurva = new CurveArray();

                foreach (Floor key in dict_SketchLines.Keys)
                {
                    List<ModelCurve> _curves = dict_SketchLines[key];
                    foreach (ModelCurve mc in _curves)
                    {

                        if (mc.GetType().ToString() == "Autodesk.Revit.DB.ModelArc" && mc.GeometryCurve.IsBound == false)
                        {
                            circleflag = true;
                        }
                        LocationCurve lcurve = mc.Location as LocationCurve;
                        Curve c = lcurve.Curve as Curve;
                        loccurva.Append(c);
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    if (circleflag == true && loccurva.Size == 2)
                    {
                        Curve tempc;
                        if (loccurva.get_Item(0).GetType().ToString() == "Autodesk.Revit.DB.Arc")
                        {
                            tempc = loccurva.get_Item(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tempc = loccurva.get_Item(1);
                        }
                        loccurva.Clear();
                        loccurva.Append(tempc);
                    }

                CurveArrArray newcurarr = new CurveArrArray();
                newcurarr.Append(loccurva);
                SortCurvesContiguousArray(newcurarr);

                TaskDialog.Show("Revit CurveArray Array Size" , newcurarr.Size.ToString());


                foreach (CurveArray ca in newcurarr)
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit CurveArray within Array Size" , ca.Size.ToString());
                }

                // Below is edited for error control - leaving out the secondary loops for now

                CurveArrArray switcharr = new CurveArrArray();
                //switcharr.Append(newcurarr.get_Item(1));
                switcharr.Append(newcurarr.get_Item(0));

                //SortCurvesContiguousArray(loccurva);
                //CurveArrArray newcurarr = new CurveArrArray();
                //newcurarr.Append(loccurva);

                double end = 1;
                SketchPlane sketch = FindElementByName( docfamily,typeof( SketchPlane ), "Ref. Level" ) as SketchPlane;
                docfamily.FamilyCreate.NewExtrusion(false, switcharr, sketch, end);

                }
                catch
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Could Not Write to Curve Array or Create Extrusion");
                }

                trans.Commit();
            }

            docfamily.Save();
            docfamily.LoadFamily(document, new CustomFamilyLoadOption());
            docfamily.Close();
            File.Delete(sfinpath);

            Family familynew = FindElementByName(document,typeof(Family),famname)as Family;
                if( null == familynew )
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Family Does Not Exist");
                }

            FilteredElementCollector collector1 = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
            ICollection<Element> collection = collector1.WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();
            List<FamilySymbol> fsym = new FilteredElementCollector(document).OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).Cast<FamilySymbol>().ToList();
            FamilySymbol famsymb = null;
            foreach (FamilySymbol symb in fsym)
            {
                if (symb.Name == famname)
                {
                    famsymb = symb as FamilySymbol;
                }
            }

            using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(document))
            {
                trans.Start("PlaceVoid");
                    if( ! famsymb.IsActive )
                    {
                        famsymb.Activate();
                    }
                    XYZ p = new XYZ(0,0,0);
                    FamilyInstance gratingvoid = document.Create.NewFamilyInstance( p, famsymb, lev, lev, StructuralType.NonStructural );
                    document.Regenerate();
                trans.Commit();
            }

    }


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


static public Element FindElementByName(Document doc,Type targetType,string targetName)
{
    return new FilteredElementCollector( doc ).OfClass( targetType ).FirstOrDefault<Element>(e => e.Name.Equals( targetName ) );
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public class CustomFamilyLoadOption : IFamilyLoadOptions
        {
            public bool OnFamilyFound(bool familyInUse,  out bool overwriteParameterValues)
            {
                overwriteParameterValues = true;
                return true;
            }

            public bool OnSharedFamilyFound(Family sharedFamily,bool familyInUse,out FamilySource source, out bool overwriteParameterValues)
            {
                source = FamilySource.Family;
                overwriteParameterValues = true;
                return true;
            }
        }


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


const double _inch = 1.0 / 12.0;
const double _sixteenth = _inch / 16.0;

static Curve CreateReversedCurve(Curve orig )
{
  //if( !IsSupported( orig ) )
  //{
  //  throw new NotImplementedException("CreateReversedCurve for type " + orig.GetType().Name );
  //}

  if( orig is Line )
  {
    //return creapp.NewLineBound(orig.GetEndPoint( 1 ), orig.GetEndPoint( 0 ) );
    return Line.CreateBound(orig.GetEndPoint( 1 ), orig.GetEndPoint( 0 ) );
  }
  else if( orig is Arc )
  {
   // return creapp.NewArc( orig.GetEndPoint( 1 ), orig.GetEndPoint( 0 ), orig.Evaluate( 0.5, true ) );
    return Arc.Create( orig.GetEndPoint( 1 ), orig.GetEndPoint( 0 ), orig.Evaluate( 0.5, true ) );
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception(
      "CreateReversedCurve - Unreachable" );
  }
}

public static void SortCurvesContiguousArray(CurveArrArray curvesarr)
{
    double _precision1 = 1.0 / 12.0 / 16.0; // around 0.00520833
    double _precision2 = 0.001; // limit for CurveLoop.Create(...)

    int cn = curvesarr.Size;
    int ci = 0;

    while (ci < cn)

 {
    CurveArray curves = curvesarr.get_Item(ci);
    ci +=1;

    // account for multiple curve loops with secondary array
    CurveArray loop1 = new CurveArray();
    CurveArray loop2 = new CurveArray();

    int n = curves.Size;
    int split = 1;

    // Walk through each curve (after the first)
    // to match up the curves in order

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Revit I Loop Run", i.ToString());
        Curve curve = curves.get_Item(i);

        if (curve.GetType().ToString() == "Autodesk.Revit.DB.Arc" && curve.IsBound == false)
        {
            break;
        }   

        XYZ beginPoint = curve.GetEndPoint(0);
        XYZ endPoint = curve.GetEndPoint(1);

        XYZ p,q;

        // Find curve with start point = end point

        bool found = (i + 1 >= n);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            p = curves.get_Item(j).GetEndPoint(0);
            q = curves.get_Item(j).GetEndPoint(1);

            // If there is a match end->start,
            // this is the next curve
            if (p.DistanceTo(endPoint) < _precision1)
            {
                if (p.DistanceTo(endPoint) > _precision2)
                {
                    XYZ intermediate = new XYZ((endPoint.X + p.X) / 2.0, (endPoint.Y + p.Y) / 2.0, (endPoint.Z + p.Z) / 2.0);

                    curves.set_Item(i, Line.CreateBound(beginPoint, intermediate));

                    curves.set_Item(j, Line.CreateBound(intermediate, q));
                }

                if (i + 1 != j)
                {
                    Curve tmp = curves.get_Item(i + 1);
                    curves.set_Item(i + 1, curves.get_Item(j));
                    curves.set_Item(j, tmp);
                }
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            // If there is a match end->end,
            // reverse the next curve

            if (q.DistanceTo(endPoint) < _precision1)
            {
                if (q.DistanceTo(endPoint) > _precision2)
                {
                    XYZ intermediate = new XYZ((endPoint.X + q.X) / 2.0, (endPoint.Y + q.Y) / 2.0, (endPoint.Z + q.Z) / 2.0);

                    curves.set_Item(i, Line.CreateBound(beginPoint, intermediate));

                    curves.set_Item(j, Line.CreateBound(p, intermediate));
                }

                if (i + 1 == j)
                {
                    curves.set_Item(i + 1, CreateReversedCurve(curves.get_Item(j)));
                }
                else
                {
                    Curve tmp = curves.get_Item(i + 1);
                    curves.set_Item(i + 1, CreateReversedCurve(curves.get_Item(j)));
                    curves.set_Item(j, tmp);
                }
                found = true;
                break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                // if not found, must be part of a new loop - move it to the back and keep going and add to second array
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit No Match Found for item", i.ToString());
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Moveing it to back of list");
                Curve tmp1 = curves.get_Item(i);
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit tmp1 Current i item endpt", tmp1.GetEndPoint(0).ToString());
                loop2.Append(tmp1);
                Curve tmp2 = curves.get_Item(n - split);
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit tmp2 Back of list item endpt", tmp2.GetEndPoint(0).ToString());

                // set current item to rear
                curves.set_Item(i, tmp2);
                // set rear item to current
                curves.set_Item(n - split, tmp1);

                TaskDialog.Show("Revit new item i endpt", curves.get_Item(i).GetEndPoint(0).ToString());
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit moved item endpt", curves.get_Item(n - split).GetEndPoint(0).ToString());

                // error testing - try to append in a different manner and check values
                    //curves.set_Item(i, Line.CreateBound(curves.get_Item(i).GetEndPoint(0), curves.get_Item(i).GetEndPoint(1)));
                    //curves.set_Item(n - split, Line.CreateBound(curves.get_Item(n - split).GetEndPoint(0), curves.get_Item(n - split).GetEndPoint(1)));
                    //Curve ncurve = Line.CreateBound(curves.get_Item(n - split).GetEndPoint(0), curves.get_Item(n - split).GetEndPoint(1));
                    //TaskDialog.Show("Revit Appended to Loop2 Endpoint", ncurve.GetEndPoint(0).ToString());
                    //loop2.Append(ncurve);

                //set the split off counter so items not fitting in first loop can be split to new array.
                split += 1;
                //reset the counter back so item moved from rear can be checked in next run of for loop
                i -= 2;
            }

            //set counter to end for loop when all items that do not fit in first loop are processed
            if (i >= n - (split + 1))
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "End Of Looping");
                TaskDialog.Show("Revit - The Split Number", split.ToString());
                i = n;
            }
        }

        int counter = 0;

        // recreate array with only items from first loop found
        while (counter <= (n - split))
        {
            loop1.Append(curves.get_Item(counter));
            counter += 1;
        }

        TaskDialog.Show("Revit loop1 Size", loop1.Size.ToString());

        curvesarr.Clear();
        curvesarr.Append(loop1);

        if (loop2.Size > 0)
        {
            string stringinfo = "";

            // run the loop detection on a second array that was split from the first

            TaskDialog.Show("Revit loop2 Size", loop2.Size.ToString());
            CurveArrArray tmpcurvesarr = new CurveArrArray();
            tmpcurvesarr.Append(loop2);
            SortCurvesContiguousArray(tmpcurvesarr);
            loop2.Clear();
            loop2 = tmpcurvesarr.get_Item(0);
            curvesarr.Append(loop2);

            foreach (Curve ccc in loop2)
            {
                stringinfo = (stringinfo + " " + ccc.GetEndPoint(0).ToString() + " - " + ccc.GetEndPoint(1).ToString());
            }
             TaskDialog.Show("Revit", stringinfo);
        }

    }

  }
}




}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Shane

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the curves into an existing extrusion in the family? I would assume that it is much easier to create a new extrusion from scratch from them instead.

Comment: Well the read only attribute started biting me,  so yes, I am now creating a new extrusion, I finally go it to work yesterday, but if the floor is not drawn in perfect order, it will not work.  I found your "SortCurvesContiguous" routine, and am stuck,  you use an IList<Curve> and I have a CurveArray(),  tried to append the curves to the list but does not work.       CurveArray loccurva = new CurveArray();     IList<Curve> curvlist = new List<Curve>(); LocationCurve lcurve = mc.Location as LocationCurve; Curve c = lcurve.Curve as Curve; loccurva.Append(c); curvlist.Append(c);

Comment: Ok,  converted your SortCurvesContiguous routine to use curvearray instead of list.  It works now with lines and arcs drawn out of order.   Last hurdle is to figure out how to find openings in floor,  the delete and rollback data does not differentiate loops.

Comment: I am further editing your SortCurvesContiguous to accept a CurveArrArray and when a curve that does not match any previous ones is found split it off into a new array. How on earth do you remove an item(by index)  from a curvearray ???

Comment: Jeremy,   I am at wits end with this one!  I have an almost working version of the SortCurvesContiguous that splits secondary loops into a new array.   It is behaving strangely,  and I tried it on a brand new fresh project and get the error "a managed exception was thrown by revit or by one of its external applications"  I have the two project files (one where it kinda works and the one with the exception) and a txt file with my sharp dev code. I do not see a way to upload these here,  do you think you could look at this at some point. updated code above. Thanks! out 4 few days be back on 15th